# how to decalre "ClientsTbl" as varible in my function c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

```cs
public static void btnDeleteAllEntire(string tbl, string pk ,DataGridView gridView)
{
    var r = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete All Records", "Delete All Records", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (r == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string sql = "DELETE FROM "+tbl+"";
        string jsonTbl = GetJsonFromSql(sql);

        string sql2 = "SELECT *";
        sql2 += "FROM "+tbl+"";
        sql2 += " Order By " + pk + "";

        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        string jsonTbl2 = GetJsonFromSql(sql2);
        List<Tables.ClientsTbl> localsal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tables.ClientsTbl>>(jsonTbl);
        gridView.DataSource = localsal;
    }
}
```

I want to ClientsTbl in my below code as a variable

Comment: It's *very* unclear to me what you're asking here. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question.

Comment: The `+""` doesn't do anything. Appending an empty string doesn't change the result. Note that the double quotes are only a syntactical boundary of a string literal but they are not part of the string value. So, you don't have to terminate the string value by appending quotes - somehow.

Comment: I want to create a method for reusing this code in all my views because this code will repeat. As you can see in my code, I made three variables, but what is missing is how to declare List<Tables.ClientsTbl> as variable , my question is it possible to declare ClientsTble "which is class" as variable?

Comment: Sounds like you should make the method generic.

Comment: Are you looking for [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to

1.create class Tables and create  subcalss ClientsTbl

2.create  namespace Tables  and create  class  ClientsTbl

then declare (create a instance of class) ClientsTbl

first craete   a namespace Tables or class ClientsTbl

```
namespace Tables
{
    public class ClientsTbl
    {
        //List feild
    }
}
```